# Why does training a tensorflow model with a tf.data pipeline yield radically different results than directly feeding with EagerTensors?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, pipeline, tf.data.dataset

I am trying to set up a pipeline to train a model. To get started, I am using 'training wheels'.
I preprocess all of my data into 5 EagerTensors -- 3 for features, 2 for targets.

For the sake of argument, lets call the feature tensors "in_a, in_b, in_c" and the target tensors "tgt_1, tgt_2"

The shape of the input tensors are as follows:

```
in_a.shape (67473, 132, 5)
in_b.shape (67473, 132)
in_c.shape (67473, 132)
```

Target tensors are:

```
tgt_1.shape (67473, 132)
tgt_2.shape (67473, 132)
```

If I feed these tensors into my model using the .fit method in the following way:
`training_model.fit(x=[in_a, in_b, in_c],y=[tgt_1, tgt_2],batch_size = 32, shuffle = True, epochs = 20)`
I get wonderful results 100% of the time that I run the fit (input data is identical in all cases)

HOWEVER, I have more data than I can fit in memory, so I am tyring to figure out the tf.data.Dataset flow, and this is where I have problems.

I take the *exact* same tensors and create a zipped dataset in the following way:

```
feature_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((a_in, b_in, c_in))
target_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tgt_1, tgt_2))
full_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((feature_ds,target_ds)).shuffle(buffer_size=320).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

This yields the following element_spec:

```
((TensorSpec(shape=(None, 132, 5), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 132), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 132), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)), (TensorSpec(shape=(None, 132), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 132), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)))
```

Now, when I feed the dataset into the exact same model, I get radically variant results - every time I train the model.

`training_model.fit(full_dataset, epochs = 20)`

One fit of 20 epochs leaves good results; another run, medocre; another, awful.

What could I be doing wrong? Any ideas how to troubleshoot this? I mean, the data source doesn't change between the two ways of feeding the model, just the method used to get it there.

Many thanks in advance!
Reefmo

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out... turns out that model.fit(shuffle=True) will shuffle the entire dataset at each epoch.

The way I zipped the full_dataset above used a .shuffle(buffer_size=320)

1. Problem here was that the dataset was some 67k records long -- and the way the shuffle works on datasets is sorta funky -- just the buffer gets shuffled, and then as data is read out, it backfills the buffer (So I think). AND the default behavior is to NOT shuffle at the end of every epoch.

By changing the line to

```
full_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((input_ds,target_ds)).shuffle(buffer_size=67000),reshuffle_each_iteration=True).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

Fixed my issue.